# 3D Object Modelling in the Brain

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, literature, psychology, computational-model

Could somebody point out the neuroscience literature dedicated to the *modelling of 3D objects* in the human mind?

I'm interested in the brain regions, and particularly the details of the circuitry, involved in simulating/manipulating (or planning to manipulate) and/or recognizing 3D objects, or in relating them to the "2D" sensory information. Ultimately, my interest is quantitative, i.e. I'd be especially interested on more computational outlooks on the topic.

Edit: I am aware of the visual recognition pathway, which roughly speaking culminates with the [inferior temporal gyrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferior_temporal_gyrus) (in the "what pathway"). However, some animals (not just humans) can *simulate* object properties (e.g. how will this plastic figurine warp if I bend it a certain way? What is that moving ballerina likely to look like in the next second?). This is more complex than object recognition alone.

Note: my question is asking for pointers to the foundational literature of this topic. I know it's somewhat broad, but I'm essentially asking where to start reading. Thanks! :)

Comment: So, you're asking for literary recommendations pertaining to how the human brain senses and interprets 3D objects? If so, me *holding* a coffee mug, and me *seeing* the same mug, involve completely different regions of the brain, yet both processes achieve the goal of recognizing the mug to be a 3D object. Given this example alone, I feel that your question yields way too broad of an answer, if one is to be given accurately and wholly. *Perhaps you should focus on a single sense..*

Comment: @Charles Thanks for your comment. I was actually thinking about the *modelling* of the object, rather than something tied to a specific sense. For instance, the [hippocampus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_memory#Location_of_semantic_memory_in_the_brain) and [PPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_parietal_cortex) both have multimodal sensory inputs, and encode something involving more than one sense. Although, if I had to choose a sense, I would say vision. I'll also edit to clarify a bit.

Comment: Is this the ability you are talking about?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_visualization_ability

Comment: @futurebird Yes, seemingly so. Though in writing my question I had more of a "simulation" view in mind, e.g. some notion of material properties must be involved when modelling the future.